# Загрузка файлов на сервер: $_FILES пустой для больших размеров файлов

Tags: php

Доброй ночи, it-знатоки! Сначала прошу прощения у **ling** за тройной ноль - слайдер не работает, хотел вручную поставить балл, аннет, видимо, значение берется с ползунка!
Вот в чем вопрос: есть html-элемент `<input name="photo_load1" type="file" size="40">`.
При отправке формы если размер файла меньше допустимого, то всё нормально: массив `$_FILES` не пустой - можно получить инфу о файле. Если размер файла больше допустимого, то `$_FILES` **пустой**, метод POST не отрабатывает и нет возможности получить инфу о файле и, соответственно, узнать его размер. Замкнутый круг! Нафига козе баян, если она играет на флейте, т.е. в скрипте нельзя осуществить проверку, **$_FILES**-то пустой!!! Недоработка PHP!

Comment: @waterman Дело в том, что очки, которыми один участник награждает другого, вычитаются из его собственной репутации. Поскольку у Вас их уже не было, когда Вы наградить ling, у Вас не получилось. Награда своими очками - это не рядовая мера, обычно достаточно 1) принять ответ (галочка слева от ответа) или проголосовать за  ответ(ладошка вверх слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

А зачем сразу кидаться проверять размер файла? Пользователь ведь мог и ничего не прикрепить. Лучше сначала проверить, пуст ли $_FILES, и только потом смотреть размер файла (хотя зачем - залился и ладно).

Answer (score 0):

Измените  `max_upload_filesize` и `max_post_size` (в гугл), в чем проблема-то? И это директивы сервера, а не PHP. Эти запросы обрывает апач.

Comment: Эти директивы я и так использую в .htaccess. Что если пользователь выберет для загрузки файл большего размера, чем в max_upload_filesize? Нужно этот момент отследить, ведь браузер не выдает никаких ошибок и пользователь будет думать, что файл загружен!

Comment: Поставьте 4 гига и отслеживайте)) `$size = filesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);` Так более понятно, для чего это сделано? 

ЗЫ: узнать размер файла на стороне клиента можно с помощью флэш-загрузчика (`google>flash upload`). PHP - серверный язык, он обрабатывает запросы и выдает ответ, т.е. какой файл выбрал клиент, он не может узнать.

Comment: Хорошая идея: 4 гига! Спасибо, Sh4dow, попробую!

Comment: Размер загружаемого файла на уровне html - работает,  только размер надо указывать в байтах, а не в килобайтах, как указано на http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlupload.php. Можно проверять даже несколько файлов, если у на форме несколько type='file', причем для каждого свой! Спасибо, GLAGOLA!!!

Answer (score 0):

Да, [[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) пошутил, если пользователь позалевает вам раз десять файлы по 4 гига на сервер, то вы вполне можете выйти за пределы квоты "бесплатного трафика" и вам придется оплатить часть превышающую "бесплатное соотношение" (зависит от хостера). Используйте флеш загрузчики, [ограничьте размер загружаемого файла на уровне html](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlupload.php) и т.д.